# Django search field select options from model fields list

Tags: django, forms, select, model, field

I have a Django list view with a search field on top of the list.

I now want this field to become a select field instead of simple text and the select options should be the field list from the underlying model.

Searched around for quite a while, but did not found an appropriate approach for this.

Any link or ideas welcome to get this things together.

Comment: take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#s-choicefield

Comment: sorry, don't want a field in the model become a choice field. There is an extra form in the template on top of the listview, where i can define filters for the listview. This is currently not bound to the model. To avoid typos in the column field i want this to be prefilled with the field names from the model.